# Transaction remains pending on RINKEBY network

Tags: etherscan, rinkeby, solc, infura, ethers.js

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const generateWallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
var toAccount = 'TO ACCOUNT';
var contractAddress = 'CONTRACT ADDRESS';
var myAddress = 'MYADDRESS';
var privateKey = Buffer.from("PrivateKey","hex");
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new                                                                             web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/ACCESS TOKEN"));
const input = fs.readFileSync('icoToken.sol');
console.log(input,"INPUT");
const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
const bytecode = output.contracts[':FixedSupplyToken'].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':FixedSupplyToken'].interface);
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,"CONTRACT ADDRESS");
var balance = contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call();
console.log("BALANCE:",balance);

var transacTObject = {
to: '0x897bb6a4f3e7c334d42f355a88fbdfbf8ce05bf2',
value: '10000000000000000',
}
web3.eth.getGasPrice(function (err, price) {
if (err) {
    return err.message;
} else {
    console.log(price, "gas");
    gasPrice = 21000000000;
    gas = web3.utils.toHex(price);
    console.log(gasPrice, "gasprice");
    gasPriceHex = web3.utils.toHex(21000000000);
    gasLimitHex = web3.utils.toHex(21000000000);
    console.log('limitHex', gasLimitHex);
    console.log('Current gasPrice: ' + gasPrice + ' OR ' + gasPriceHex);
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return err.message;
        } else {
            console.log(data, "NONCE");
            nonce = data + 6;
            nonceHex = web3.utils.toHex(nonce);
            console.log('nonce (transaction count on fromAccount): ' +       nonce + '(' + nonceHex + ')');


            tokenTransfer =  contract.methods.transfer('RECEIVER ADDRESS',"1000000000000000000").encodeABI();
            if (tokenTransfer) {
                console.log(tokenTransfer, "tokenTransfer");
            }
            var rawTx = {
                nonce: nonceHex,
                gas: 100006,
                gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
                gasLimit: gasLimitHex,
                to: contractAddress,
                from: myAddress,
                value: '0x00',
                data: tokenTransfer,
                chainId: 4,
            };
            var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
            tx.sign(privateKey);
            var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
            console.log(serializedTx, "SERIALIZETX");

            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function (err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error:');
                    console.log(err.message);
                } else {
                    console.log('Transaction receipt hash pending');
                    console.log(hash);
                    web3.eth.getTransaction(hash, function (err, hash1) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error:');
                            console.log(err.message);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Transaction receipt:', hash1);

                            web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash, function (err, hash2) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log('Error:');
                                    console.log(err.message);
                                } else {
                                    console.log('Transaction receipt:', hash2);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

})

Comment: Did you try to resubmit it with a higher gas price?

Comment: You are adding 6 to the value returned by `getTransactionCount`, nonces have to be consecutive numbers so your transaction will be pending until all nonces before `getTransactionCount() + 6` are mined previously.